# How do I check via jQuery if a jQuery Mobile popup is open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm able to activate the following jQuery Mobile popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="waiting1" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="30,15" data-dismissible="false">
     <div class="modalAlert" id="waitingContent">
      Waiting...
     </div> 
</div>
```

using the jQuery command:

```
$(waiting1).popup('open');
```

but then I want to confirm programmatically that the popup opened, and trigger an alert using an IF statement if it didn't. I tried using the CSS display attribute:

```
if ( $(waiting1).css('display') != 'block') {
    alert(
        "Error: Waiting popup should not be visible."
    );
    return( -1 );
};
```

...but as a jQuery Mobile popup, apparently the attribute is always "block" whether it's visible or not. What's the proper way to check this within the IF statement? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile, a class gets applied to the popup's container when it appears. `ui-popup-active` when it's visible, `ui-popup-hidden` when it's hidden. Therefore instead of checking for `'block'` or `':visible'`, you could check for the that class:

```
if ( $(waiting1).parent().hasClass('ui-popup-hidden')) {
    alert(
        "Error: Waiting popup should not be visible."
    );
    return( -1 );
};
```

Comment: That was fast! 

Just to be clear, the error for `ui-popup-hidden` would warn that the popup SHOULD be visible. But this was the definitely the answer I was looking for, and I spent at least an hour looking, and it worked, so thanks very much!

Comment: Seems not to work in iOS' Safari but works in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the jQuery Mobile Popup mutex:

```
if ($.mobile.popup.active && $.mobile.popup.active.element[0] === $(waiting1)[0]) {
alert('popup is opened');
}
```

Comment: Tested in iOS and Android: Safari, Chrome, Firefox -> Works everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Suppose popup has the class **popupLogin**

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.find(".popupLogin").parent().hasClass("ui-popup-active")){
     alert('popup is open');
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umerqureshi/fuy4Lz5z/

Comment: this answer is better, but please note before any popup transition (like fade, slide..) was done, the 'ui-popup-active' will not appeared! if u check a poup right after popup("open"), in this case Michael method still work or use 'none'  transition

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if(!$.mobile.activePage.find(popupID).is(":visible")) $(popupID).popup('close');
```